# How can i set the same time scale (?) in in-unity game player and game build?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, time, build

i have a problem with time scale or something like this. The game object should rotating, and i write this:

```
void Update {
transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * speed);
}
```

But, when i create the build of game, then in "build-edition" speed gets slower. What should i do? I can give video of this.

Comment: Your question needs more details. Please leave a video. Explain what your game is and share some of your research.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [`Time.deltaTime`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html), which outputs the time difference between the last frame and new frame.
Very much needed as a higher FPS means that more `Update()`s are called, resulting inconsistencies in movement.

Multiplying any movement by time-scale will help to normalize the movement across different FPS.

```cs
void Update() {
    // Will rotate significantly slower, increase the 'speed' variable.
    // But rotation speed will normalize across different FPS.
    transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * speed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```